# Copy an element and truncate it with xslt

Tags: xslt

I am trying to select all the table cells in a particular column and truncate them down to 10 characters.

I really can't fault this syntax.

```
 <xsl:template match="table[contains(@class, 'listing')]//tr/td[contains(@class, 'listing-body-start')]">
     <td>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring(./text(), 1, 10)"/>
     </td>
 </xsl:template>
```

I can replace the contents of the cell with static text, or replicate the same text by using select=".", but as soon as I try this substring method, the cells dissappear.

Comment: Please post your input and complete XSLT with expected output.

Comment: Do they disappear in the XSLT output or only when interpreted by program reading the XSLT output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `text()`. It's generally bad practice.

Use

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 10)"/>
```

This works on the string value of the td element, rather than on its child text nodes. In many content models it would be normal for a td element to contain other elements as children, e.g. a p or para element, and in that case looking for the child text nodes will fail.

This answer is a guess. If you don't tell us what's in your input, we have no choice but to guess.